# Parallels deleted my Windows Start Volume

Tags: windows, boot-camp, parallels, osx-el-capitan

I installed Parallels on Mac OSX el capitan. 
Before, I had a win 10 bootcamp start volume. After installing Parallels, the start volume disappeared from settings -> start volume and I can't boot my bootcamp partition any longer. I can only access it via parallels.

Is there any hint, how I can make the partition bootable again?

I also lost my windows activation :/

thanks!

Comment: Did you use Parallels to import your Boot Camp volume as a Parallels VM? If so, you need to shut it down fully before you can boot to it from Boot Camp.

Comment: that solved my problem. If you answer the question i can accept it as answer.

Comment: Done. It's a bit short… but that's really all there is to it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Parallels to import your Boot Camp volume to use as a virtual machine, you must ensure you shut it down fully after using it, in order that it will boot correctly from Boot Camp.